# SQL Server CE with Sync Framework SP1 and SP2

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I couldnt think of a good title so please read the question here:

I have a SQL-CE Database in a WinForms Application which is using the Sync-Framework for a simple DownloadOnly Syncronization. Since i have some users with SQL-CE SP1 and some with SP2 installed, i need to know, which steps to follow to make the Sync-Framework work against both Versions.

Should i deliver the Sync-Framework-DLLs with my Setup.msi or give them a specific version of the Sync-Framework download on Microsofts Homepage? Do i need to do some could changes?

Installing SQL-CE SP2 on all computers is not an option as the administrator is frightend that other appliations (also with Sync-Framework) are not downward-compatible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you an overview of the options: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/clarifying-sync-framework-and-sql-server-compact-compatibility.aspx